# Finding $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}({1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+...+{1\over n+n})$ using integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Finding $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left({1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+\dots+{1\over n+n}\right)$. I tried many things but it would work out. I am now studying calculus 2 (In my country the first calculus course is split, and I saw a solution while studying calculus 1.)  However, I understood that questions with sum are usually solved like that: For example, 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{1\over n^{k+1}}({1^k+2^k+ \ldots +n^k})= \ldots =\lim_{n\to \infty}{1\over n}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\Bigl({j\over n}\Bigr)^k}=\int_{0}^{1}{x^k}\,dx
$$ 
but now I can't bring it to that form. I also can't verify my answer because I can't find other answers for it. I would really appreciate your help. Please don't mark my question is a duplicate before making sure that either the origin involves integrals **or** that it cannot be solved with integrals.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n+k} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{1+ \frac{k}{n}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Riemann summation :

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}n}=_{n\infty}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\ln2$

Comment: Okay, I was really really close. Just had to divide the fraction parts by n, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+k}=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac kn}.$$

Comment: Actually I did it, but instead I wrote $n\over n+k$

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate by an integral this way:

$$
\int_x^{2x} \frac{\mathrm d x} {x} = \ln(2x)-\ln x  = \ln 2  \approx 0.6931
$$

You would need to prove that the difference between the integral and the summation vanishes for $n \rightarrow \infty$. One way to do this is to note that the summation is actually a [Riemman sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) that converges to the integral.